# Show and Hide Divs based on radio selection

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

By default `custom_2`, `custom_3`, `custom_4` divs should remain hidden.

- Only If "Radio 1" is selected div id "custom_2" is shown
- Only If "Radio 2" is selected div id "custom_3" is shown
- Only If "Radio 3" is selected div id "custom_4" is shown
- I also have other divs within the same parent DIV like custom_5, custom_6. These should  **NOT** be **affected.**

I have tried below but it's not working. Can anyone help please? Here is the jQuery:

```
CRM.$(function ($) {
  $("input[name$='custom_1']").click(function () {
    var test = $(this).val();
    $("#custom_2").hide();
    $("#custom_3" + test).show();
  });
});
```

And here is the HTML:

```
    <div class="ShowHide">
      Radio 1 <input type="radio" name="custom_1" value="1" id="CIVICRM_QFID_1 " /> 
Radio 2 <input type="radio" name="custom_1" value="2" id="CIVICRM_QFID_2" /> 
Radio 3 <input type="radio" name="custom_1" value="3" id="CIVICRM_QFID_3" />

      <div id="custom_2" class="crm-section custom_2-section form-item">Radio 1 Selected</div>
      <div id="custom_3" class="crm-section custom_3-section form-item">Radio 2 Selected</div>
      <div id="custom_4" class="crm-section custom_4-section form-item">Radio 3 Selected</div>
      <div id="custom_5" class="crm-section custom_5-section form-item"></div>
      <div id="custom_6" class="crm-section custom_6-section form-item"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: is that a typo above - you have two `div` elements that both say `Radio 2 Selected`?? Also, does the DIV to be shown have an ID numerically 1 more than radio button value?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Yes, there's a typo. Corrected it now. Cheers

Comment: Can you clarify the rules to show certain DIV elements and not others?

Comment: I have updated my HTML to show other divs like custom_5 & custom_6 in the parent element, they should not be affected.

Comment: OK - but as I said in a comment below, other DIV elements will not be affected as the ID is unique and only 1 element will match. If there is a radio button with value 5 then div#custom_6 would be shown... there must be some logic used to determine which are or are not shown

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by hiding all divs using a class and then showing the div you want using id, here is an example

html:

```
<div id="ShowHide">
        Radio 1 <input type="radio" name="custom_1" value="1" id="CIVICRM_QFID_1 " />
        Radio 2 <input type="radio" name="custom_1" value="2" id="CIVICRM_QFID_2" />
        <div id="custom_1" class="radio-div">Radio 1 Selected</div>
        <div id="custom_2" class="radio-div">Radio 2 Selected</div>
    </div>
```

js:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.radio-div').hide()
    $("input[name$='custom_1']").on('click', (e) => {
        $('.radio-div').hide()
        $("#custom_" + $(e.currentTarget).val()).show()
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, I also have other divs on the same page like custom_5, custom_6 and didn't want this js to affect other fields. Sorry, updated my post.

Comment: your welcome, what about selecting from inside a specific container like : $(".crm-section input[name$='custom_1']") and $('.crm-section .radio-div')

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `DIV` element to be displayed has an ID with an integer suffix greater than the value of the radio button being checked one could, using vanilla JS, accomplish the show/hide like this:

```js
/*
  a delegated event handler bound to the parent container (edited question, edited parent)
  will process "change" events on all radio buttons within
  that parent element.
  
  DIV elements are selected in relation to this parent
  element only.
*/
document.addEventListener('change',e=>{
  if( e.target instanceof HTMLInputElement && e.target.type=='radio' ){
    /*
      find the numeric value of the radio button (event.target)
      and increment by one
    */
    let i=Number( e.target.value );
        i++;
    /*
      create the suitable ID or className attribute
      used to identify the DIV element
    */
    let id=`#custom_${i}`;
    /*
      If the DIV exists, hide all previously displayed DIV elements
      and show the relevant content
    */
    let div=e.target.parentNode.querySelector( id );
    if( div ){
      e.target.parentNode.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(div=>div.style.display='none');
      div.style.display='block';
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.ShowHide{
  margin:1rem 0;
  padding:1rem;
  border:1px dotted grey
}

.ShowHide > div{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="ShowHide">

  Radio 1 <input type="radio" name="custom_1" value="1" id="CIVICRM_QFID_1 "/>
  Radio 2 <input type="radio" name="custom_1" value="2" id="CIVICRM_QFID_2" />
  Radio 3 <input type="radio" name="custom_1" value="3" id="CIVICRM_QFID_3" />
  Radio 4 <input type="radio" name="custom_1" value="4" id="CIVICRM_QFID_4 "/>
  <div id="custom_2">Radio 1 Selected</div>
  <div id="custom_3">Radio 2 Selected</div>
  <div id="custom_4">Radio 3 Selected</div>
  <div id="custom_5">Radio 4 Selected</div>
  <div id="custom_6">Radio 5 Selected - will not be shown</div>
  <div id="custom_7">Radio 6 Selected - neither will this</div>
</div>


<div class="ShowHide">
  Radio 23 <input type="radio" name="custom_2" value="23" id="CIVICRM_QFID_23 "/>
  Radio 24 <input type="radio" name="custom_2" value="24" id="CIVICRM_QFID_24" />
  Radio 25 <input type="radio" name="custom_2" value="25" id="CIVICRM_QFID_25" />
  <div id="custom_24">Radio 23 Selected</div>
  <div id="custom_25">Radio 24 Selected</div>
  <div id="custom_26">Radio 25 Selected</div>
  <div id="custom_27">Radio 27 Selected - will not be shown</div>
  <div id="custom_29">Radio 28 Selected - neither will this</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I have other divs on the same page which follows the same ID patterns, and are dynamically generated. but would not like them being affected.
If I can limit the div ID's then Your answer is what I am looking for.

Comment: If they are within the same parent element they might be affected - if they are not in the same parent they will be unaffected

Comment: They are within the same parent element.

Comment: There can only be 1 DIV that would have the correct ID

Answer (score 0):

The following approach uses the relationship between the values of the radio buttons (1, 2, 3) and the position of the `<div>` elements to be shown or hidden.

```js
function toggle(val) {
  $("#ShowHide div").each(function(i) {
    if (i + 1 === val) $(this).show();
    else $(this).hide();
  });
}
$("input[name$='custom_1']").click(function() {
  toggle(Number($(this).val()));
});
toggle(0); // hide all initially
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ShowHide">
  Radio 1 <input type="radio" name="custom_1" value="1" id="CIVICRM_QFID_1 " />
  Radio 2 <input type="radio" name="custom_1" value="2" id="CIVICRM_QFID_2" />
  Radio 3 <input type="radio" name="custom_1" value="3" id="CIVICRM_QFID_3" />
  <div id="custom_2" class="crm-section custom_2-section form-item">Radio 1 Selected</div>
  <div id="custom_3" class="crm-section custom_3-section form-item">Radio 2 Selected</div>
  <div id="custom_4" class="crm-section custom_4-section form-item">Radio 3 Selected</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a CSS solution using the functional [`:has()` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has):

```css
.crm-section {
  display: none;
}

:has(#CIVICRM_QFID_1:checked) #custom_2,
:has(#CIVICRM_QFID_2:checked) #custom_3,
:has(#CIVICRM_QFID_3:checked) #custom_4{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="ShowHide">
  <label>Radio 1 <input type="radio" name="custom_1" value="1" id="CIVICRM_QFID_1"></label>
  <label>Radio 2 <input type="radio" name="custom_1" value="2" id="CIVICRM_QFID_2"></label>
  <label>Radio 3 <input type="radio" name="custom_1" value="3" id="CIVICRM_QFID_3"></label>

  <div id="custom_2" class="crm-section form-item">Radio 1 Selected</div>
  <div id="custom_3" class="crm-section form-item">Radio 2 Selected</div>
  <div id="custom_4" class="crm-section form-item">Radio 3 Selected</div>
  <div id="custom_5" class="crm-section form-item">Some other DIV 1</div>
  <div id="custom_6" class="crm-section form-item">Some other DIV 2</div>
</div>
```

and another one using `~` general sibling combinator selector

```css
.crm-section {
  display: none;
}

#CIVICRM_QFID_1:checked ~ #custom_2,
#CIVICRM_QFID_2:checked ~ #custom_3,
#CIVICRM_QFID_3:checked ~ #custom_4{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="ShowHide">
  Radio 1 <input type="radio" name="custom_1" value="1" id="CIVICRM_QFID_1">
  Radio 2 <input type="radio" name="custom_1" value="2" id="CIVICRM_QFID_2">
  Radio 3 <input type="radio" name="custom_1" value="3" id="CIVICRM_QFID_3">

  <div id="custom_2" class="crm-section form-item">Radio 1 Selected</div>
  <div id="custom_3" class="crm-section form-item">Radio 2 Selected</div>
  <div id="custom_4" class="crm-section form-item">Radio 3 Selected</div>
  <div id="custom_5" class="crm-section form-item">Some other DIV 1</div>
  <div id="custom_6" class="crm-section form-item">Some other DIV 2</div>
</div>
```